# Orthogonal complement of closed subset in Hilbert space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Consider a subset $K\subset L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$
K=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\mid \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}: \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx=0\}
$$

I want to determine the orthogonal complement $K^\bot$ in this Hilbert space. I was already able to verify that $K$ is a closed subset. So if I would somehow be able to suggest how the orthogonal complement should look like by a small calculation, then I can simply verify that this suggestion is correct by verifying that $(K^\bot)^\bot=K$ holds.

I know the calculation should start in the trend of: let $g\in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in K$ s.t.
\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx \\
&= ...,\\
\end{align}
which should equal zero, where the term that remains inside the integral might then tell us something about the elements of $K^\bot$. However, it is not clear what manipulative calculation I should perform. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is defined by the relation $$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1)}(x)\,dx = 0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$  That looks a lot like we're defining basic elements of $K^\perp.$  In particular, this seems to define $$K^\perp = \{g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, g \text{ is constant on } [n,n+1)\}$$
which can be naturally identified with $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: I don't see why it should be constant? Shouldn't it be that $g(x)=0$ almost everywhere on $[n,n+1)$?

Comment: Ow ok, I see why! Is it because if $g$ would be non-zero the product would be no longer zero?

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ consist of functions that have a constant value $c_n$ on $(n,n+1)$ ($n\in \mathbb Z$) with $\sum_n |c_n|^{2} <\infty$.  Using the fact that convergence in $L^{2}$ implies almost everywhere convergence of some subsequence we can easily see that $M$ is a closed subspace of $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$. $K$ is  nothing  but $M^{\perp}$. Hence $K^{\perp}=M^{\perp \perp}=M$.

Comment: How exactly do you argue that M is closed?

Comment: @Sim My answer was wrong . I have corrected it.